# achieving unbiased randomization in constraint space with or-tools

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I have a simple code with [or-tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/overview) where I try to randomize 3 variables such that their sum is a constant. I also added random hints so that the solver will give different results each time. However, when I try to see the frequency of different values, only the first variable seems to be unbiased or following uniform distribution and all other variables are biased towards 0.

Here is the code

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = cp_model.CpModel()

mx = 500
x = model.NewIntVar(0, mx, 'x')
y = model.NewIntVar(0, mx, 'y')
z = model.NewIntVar(0, mx, 'z')

freqX = [0] * (mx + 1)
freqY = [0] * (mx + 1)
freqZ = [0] * (mx + 1)

model.Add(x + y + z == mx)
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.cp_model_presolve = False

for i in range(10000):
    model.ClearAssumptions()
    model.ClearHints()
    model.AddHint(x, np.random.randint(0, mx))
    model.AddHint(y, np.random.randint(0, mx))
    model.AddHint(z, np.random.randint(0, mx))
    
    status = solver.Solve(model)
    
    freqX[solver.Value(x)] += 1
    freqY[solver.Value(y)] += 1
    freqZ[solver.Value(z)] += 1

plt.subplot(311)
plt.bar(range(mx+1), freqX, width=1.0)
plt.subplot(312)
plt.bar(range(mx+1), freqY, width=1.0)
plt.subplot(313)
plt.bar(range(mx+1), freqZ, width=1.0)
plt.savefig('foo.svg')
```

and here is the output

[image]

What is the most scalable way to make the variables follow uniform distribution / unbiased

PS: Below is the distribution I got with invalid hints as suggested in the comments.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hints work in the following way:

- The search takes hint in sequence, and try to branch on the value in the hint.
- If the value is not part of the domain of the variable at that time, it select the next variable
- when failure occurs, it backtracks and select another value/variable.
- after 10 failures, it revert gradually towards the default heuristic (smallest domain, min value).

So:

- if the problem is easy, hints are valid,  and the distribution will be good
- if constraints start propagating, and make the hint invalid, because of the order of variables, the last one will be biased towards (a) the valid part, and (b) the heuristic value.

Conclusion:

- Just try randomizing the order of variables in the hint :-)

Comment: laurent-perron would it not create a circular problem if we should give valid hints. We need to solve constraints to give valid hints, do you mean just valid values in the corresponding variable range? I am doing that already

Comment: I am just saying that if you give invalid hints. The probability the hinted value appears in the solution decreases along the sequence. Thus randomizing the order of the sequence should help.

Comment: laurent-perron, I just tried it, with invalid values, all variables are getting biased. Added a new image to show that

Comment: Still the same behavior with latest ortools python package, any clues please?

Comment: We have not worked on that part at all, so unsurprisingly, the result is the same :-)

Comment: Is there something I can try, any leads on what to tweak?

Comment: laurent-perron, In order to use or-tools in any other tool, we need to be able to generate pseudo-random solutions, not predictable ones. I think this will help us and many others and expand the usage of or-tools greatly. Can you please help me understand if this is a usage error or as designed? Is there something I can hack or parameters that I can pass to achieve the same?

Comment: It ia just hard and not implemented. All solvers have heuristics that work against diversity (gradient, dual reductions, branching heuristics).

Comment: Is it possible to generate a hint from the possible solutions of current variable? I am in particular interested in CP-SAT only

Comment: ?? You mean multiple values per variable ?

Comment: For CP-SAT problems, after constraint propagation, when we have possible ranges, is it possible to generate random hints from the set of valid ranges for each variable? (Just in integer domain). I am looking for some level of control. I am not an expert in constraint solving but Systemverilog as a language has this feature where it will generate random solutions for a given set of constraints, Can we get it with or-tools?

Comment: You can, but any repair of the hint is biased.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252843/discussion-between-krishna-and-laurent-perron).